# Where to find Qt 5 downloaded pack in my Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)

Tags: application-development

I'm trying to locate the [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) 5 package in my Ubuntu 13.04 OS ([HP Compaq 6910](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hewlett-Packard_products#Business_Notebook)) following the instructions given in *[Get started](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started)* where it says:

> Alternatively, for those using Ubuntu 13.04 or a development release:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk

After downloading the package I just can't locate it. How do I locate/call the [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) if it doesn't appear anywhere in my computer?

Comment: Try `sudo ubuntu-sdk`, it should start the sdk, or try `ubuntu-sdk -h` have you tried to Google on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend following the steps on http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

The tutorial in step 2 will show you how to start using the SDK, but in essence, you can simply open the Dash, and type `qt creator` to start writing apps.

The `ubuntu-sdk` package is simply a metapackage that will install all the bits and pieces that are part of the SDK, so you won't find any content in there. In any case, to answer the question:

- To check if the package is installed, run this command on a terminal: `apt-cache policy ubuntu-sdk`
- To see the contents of the package, run this command on a terminal (as mentioned, the package is mostly empty): `dpkg -L ubuntu-sdk`